# Removing tag from question because of accepted answer

Tags: discussion, tags, editing-help

I just saw this (relatively) highly upvoted question: [Initialization of a normal array with one default value](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1065774/c-c-initialization-of-a-normal-array-with-one-default-value) which manages to ask the question in the title (but then provides more code in the question ... basically a well asked question).  The accepted answer however is " Use `std::fill()`.  Hang on a second, didn't that question ask how to initialize an array in C/C++ (and is tagged as such)?

So I was wanting to remove the C tag (tagging questions as C and C++ is one of my biggest annoyances because I know next to nothing about C++ so I follow the C tag only to find out the asker really meant C++).  However this question *is* valid for C, but the answer they have accepted means that this question/answer pair is really only valid for C++ (and if that is the answer they were happy with perhaps they really did mean to ask for C++ and not C).

What is the best move? Edit the question to remove C from the title, body and tag? Edit the answer significantly to add the differences between C and C++ (only I don't want to double or more the size of an answer that has so many up votes). Help Meta, help!

Answer (score 7, accepted):

There isn't only the accepted answer, though I concede that (nearly) always gets the best spot.

And if you look a bit further, you get the full explanation for both.